# working with dynamically allocated memory (pointer)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, io, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was playing around with pointers and dynamic memory as I'm trying to learn C++ and I keep getting this error when I compile.

```
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

My code is as follows:

```
int * ageP;    
ageP = new (nothrow) int;

if (ageP == 0)
{
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
}
else
{
    cout<<"What is your age?"<<endl;
    cin>> ageP;                       <--this is the error line
    youDoneIt(ageP);                                            
    delete ageP;
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6):

You have pointer `ageP` that points to memory, allocated by this call: `ageP = new int;` You can access this memory by dereferencing your pointer (i.e. by using the [dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator): `*ageP`):

```
  MEMORY
|        |
|--------|
|  ageP  | - - - 
|--------|      |
|  ...   |      |
|--------|      |
| *ageP  | < - -
|--------|
|        |
```

And then it's same like you would be working with variable of type `int`, so before when you worked with variable of type `int` like this:

```
int age;
cin >> age;
```

now it will become:

```
int *ageP = new int;
cin >> *ageP;
```

Comment: Last line should say `ageP`.  Otherwise good solution and nice explanation.

Comment: Yeah, that was typo :) By the way my answer doesn't say anything about  *"stack vs. heap"* or *"automatic vs. dynamic storage duration"* because I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need a reference to an int, not an int*.  For instance

```
int ageP;
cin >> ageP;
```

Thus, the delete is also unnecessary as you won't be utilizing a pointer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - really.  I'm editing the name out... now that I have flair.

Answer (score 2):

John is essentially correct that your problem is supplying a pointer where a reference is expected.

However, since you're trying to learn about dynamic allocation, using an automatic variable is not a good solution.  Instead, you can create a reference from a pointer using the `*` dereference operator.

```
int* ageP = new (nothrow) int;
std::cout << "What is your age?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> *ageP;                                           
delete ageP;
```